# I am writing an express app with form for the users to log in

Tags: express

I am writing an express app with a form to log in. For the password I am using bcryptjs and I have a git ignore file for the secret_key.I have 2 files for controller - one for users , one for controller

The error

```
Error: secret option required for sessions
    at session (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express-session/index.js:199:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/cookie-parser/index.js:70:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/student_131/wdi/UNIT_02/HW/HW_U02_D10_Todo-App/toDo_app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7

UsersControler:
usersController.create = (req, res) =>{
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt);
    User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password_digest: hash,
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
    }).then(user =>{
        req.login(user, (err)=>{
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.redirect('/user');
        });
    }).catch(err =>{
        console.log('create user'+err);
        res.status(500).json({error: err});
    });
}







    This is from app.js :
    const express = require('express');
    const logger = require('morgan');
    const path = require('path');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const methodOverride = require('method-override');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const session = require('express-session');
    const passport = require('passport');
    // initialize the app
    const app = express();

    require('dotenv').config();
```

Comment: When are you getting this error? Please, give us some context when the error is happening!

Comment: The server is running , but when I go to the browser I see this Error: secret option required for sessions.

Comment: The stack trace shows that the error is being thrown by `express-session`. So [look here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#secret).

Comment: Thank you I did already maybe I just can not find what I am missing

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'key',
 ...
});

app.use(cookieParser('key'));
app.use(express.cookieParser('key'));
```

check the same key?